# Is `1 < 2` a `not_test` in Boolean operation even without the keyword `not`?

Tags: python, syntax, grammar, lexical

I'm reading the Python documentation 2.76

[This is the lexical syntax of the 3 kinds of boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or_test) :

```
or_test  ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test
and_test ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test
not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test
```

[This is the lexical syntax for comparision](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comparison):

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
                 | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

[and the lexical syntax for or_expr](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-and_expr):

```
and_expr ::=  shift_expr | and_expr "&" shift_expr
xor_expr ::=  and_expr | xor_expr "^" and_expr
or_expr  ::=  xor_expr | or_expr "|" xor_expr
```

The Notation in the document is explained here:

[A vertical bar (|) is used to separate alternatives; it is the least binding operator in this notation.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/introduction.html#notation)

Now comes the question:

1. Is `not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test` parsed like

   `not_test ::=  comparison | ("not" not_test)`?
2. If `1.` is true, a valid `comparison` is also a valid `not_test`.(e.g. `1 < 2` is a `not_test` even without a `not` in it.)
3. In addition, because a valid `and_test` can just be a single valid `not_test`, `1 < 2` is a valid `and_test` as well. 
   The same goes for the `or_test`.
4. Then what is a valid `comparison`? `1 < 2` fits the pattern obviously. And thoese bitwise comparison expr are aslo valid `comparison`. What's in common is that the presense of at least one operator('>','<',or bitwise stuff) is required. (I'm not sure.)
5. Here comes to the weird part. Consider `x and y` for example. According to

`and_test ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test`

`and_test ::=  not_test | (and_test "and" not_test)`  # parsed like this I believe?

If it is true that `x and y` is a valid `and_test` (it can never be a `not_test` for the presence of `and`), then `x` must be a valid `and_test` which can just be one valid `not_test`. And `y` must be a valid `not_test` too.

A `not_test` can either be a single `comparison` or another `not_test` preceeded by `not`.  So a `not_test` is basically zero or more `not`s followed by one `comparison`. What matters now is the lexical syntax of `comparison`.

According to `4.`, a `comparison` must have at least one operator whatever. But this is conflict with the following example:

assign x = 3,  y = 4 . `3 and 4` seems a valid `and_test`.

But I don't see how `3` or `4` can be valid `comparison`.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal grammar specifies *precedence* in addition to simply defining the parts of the language. That's why many of the grammar nodes for expression parts contain a left-hand alternative which doesn't fit the actual name of the node; these alternatives specify a grammar node which has the next-highest precedence (thus, when expanding the tree, you would expand low precedence operations followed by high precedence operations).

This is clearest in the arithmetic operators:

```
power ::=  primary ["**" u_expr]
u_expr ::=  power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr
m_expr ::=  u_expr | m_expr "*" u_expr | m_expr "//" u_expr | m_expr "/" u_expr
            | m_expr "%" u_expr
a_expr ::=  m_expr | a_expr "+" m_expr | a_expr "-" m_expr
shift_expr ::=  a_expr | shift_expr ( "<<" | ">>" ) a_expr
```

Observe that `u_expr` has `power` as one of its alternatives, since `power` binds tighter than unaries (at least on the left). `m_expr` can expand to a `u_expr` because unaries bind tighter than multiplication operations, and `a_expr` can expand to a `m_expr` because multiplication operations bind tighter than addition operations. These statements are not attempting to imply that you should consider the statement `x * y` to actually be an addition operation (though it can be considered a *term* in a one-term addition, in the grammatical sense).

---

What this means, basically, is that you can trace along the LHS of the nodes until you reach one that parses your expression.

For example, the expression `3 + 4` is a valid `comparison` according to the grammar (though it isn't a "comparison" in the general language sense). This is because you can expand it according to the chain

```
comparison > or_expr > xor_expr > and_expr > shift_expr > a_expr > a_expr + m_expr
```

and further with

```
a_expr > m_expr > u_expr > power > primary > atom > literal > integer > decimalinteger > etc...
```

At each stage, you basically ascend the precedence chain by one rank, which gives a very clean way to determine what the order of operations is.

Answer (score 3):

The "*" means **zero or more** instances of the contained sequence. A `comparison` does *not* require an operator, as can be shown by tracing through `shift_expr`, to `primary`, `atom`, and subsequently `literal`.

Comment: Thank you,too! That was a long way to trace back to literal."

Answer (score 1):

Let's parse your question statement :):

#### Is `1 < 2` a `not_test`?

```
not_test: 'not' not_test | comparison

# `comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*`
not_test: expr comp_op expr

# `comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'`
not_test: expr < expr

# `expr: xor_expr ('|' xor_expr)*`
not_test: xor_expr < xor_expr

# `xor_expr: and_expr ('^' and_expr)*`
not_test: and_expr < and_expr

# `and_expr: shift_expr ('&' shift_expr)*`
not_test: shift_expr < shift_expr

# shift_expr: arith_expr (('<<'|'>>') arith_expr)*
not_test: arith_expr < arith_expr

# arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
not_test: term < term

# term: factor (('*'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
not_test: factor < factor

# factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
not_test: power < power

# power: atom trailer* ['**' factor]
not_test: atom < atom

#atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
#       '[' [listmaker] ']' |
#       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
#       '`' testlist1 '`' |
#       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+)
not_test: NUMBER < NUMBER
not_test: 1 < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Order matters, so the parens are used for grouping, so no.
2. NA, because 1 is not true

So I think your logic starts to break down here. What's important here is that these are statements of logic.  Not just ["yields True if its argument is False, and False otherwise"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or_test)

So the first value is given to the `not_test` (by way of `or_test` and `and_test`), then the second value is given to the `not_test` and then they are compared, which returns a boolean.